# Estimating the $n$th partial sum of a series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For integers $n \geq 2$, define
\begin{equation}
S_n := \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i^{1/\log_2(n)}} \Big( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \Big)^i \Big( 1 - \frac{i}{n} \Big).
\end{equation}
I want to get a "good" estimate on how large $S_n$ is, in terms of the index $n$. I have the numerical observations that $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_2(n)}{n} S_n = \infty.
\end{equation} 
So the growth rate of $S_n$ is at least $n / \log_2(n)$. Anyone has an idea? Thanks very much.

Comment: Numerically it appears that $S_n=O(n)$

Comment: I'd assume it acts like $n/e$ or $n/(2e) $. You can find an easy approximation if you omit the $1/i^{1/\log_2(n)} $ because it is bounded below by $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. May I ask you an additional thing: if I redefine $S_n := \sum_{i=2}^n 1/i^{1/\log_2(n)} (1 - 1/\sqrt{n})^i (1 - i / \sqrt{n})$ (in the second and third terms in each summand, I replaced $n$ in the denominators by $\sqrt{n}$), then numerically I see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\log_2(n) / \sqrt{n}) S_n$ converges to a limit $\approx 0.7$. So in this case $S_n$ scales like $\sqrt{n} / \log_2(n)$. But in this case can you simplify the expression of $S_n$ and get an estimate? Thanks very much.

Comment: Numerically $S_n$ *seems* to be very linear with $n$. Computing up to $S_{1000}$, the linear model $S_n=a+b n$ gives $R^2=0.999983$ with $$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.18747 & 0.03352 & \{1.12170,1.25325\} \\
 b & 0.21819 & 0.00006 & \{0.21807,0.21830\} \\
\end{array}$$